# Find an Object in Array of JSONs and add a value to it

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have an array of JSONs like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jack'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Peter'
  }
]
```

I want to find an object via it's `id` and add a `deleted: true` to it.

I'm wondering whats the easiest way to do this.

Comment: You can use the find method for the same

Comment: i created code pen based on the answer in the original question. you can check it here: https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/Vwawrya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below generic function which needs you to pass the array and id of the object you want to update .

```js
var arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jack'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Peter'
  }
];

 function addProperty(data,id){
data.forEach(obj => {
  if(obj.id === id){
    obj['deleted'] = true;
  }
});
   return data;
 }

let id = 1;
console.log(addProperty(arr, id));
```

Comment: You shouldn't change the object inside `find` like that. Either use the return value of `.find(obj => obj.id === 1)`, or use `forEach` instead of `find`

Comment: @RoToRa , I updated the answer , thank you for pointing it out .

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) this would be the easiest way to do it

```js
let users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jack'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Peter'
  }
];
let id = 3;
let foundUser = users.find(user => user.id === id);

console.log('Users before modification', users);
foundUser.deleted = true;
console.log('Users after modification', users);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var array = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Jack'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Peter'
    }
]

for (var item in array){
    if (array[item].id === 1){
        array[item].deleted = true;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(array)
```

What it does is loop through every item in the array. It then checks if the corresponding indexed item has the value we are looking for. If yes, it adds a `true` attribute called `deleted` and breaks out of the loop.